# Excel 2013 time enter function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to enter hhmm and for it to appear as a time for example; 1233 12:33.

and 2245 as 22:45

Then I will need to plot these times on the x axis of a graph.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1** in **B1** enter:

```
=TIME(LEFT(A1,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)
```

and format **B1** as *hh:mm*